# How to integrate Angular 6 app with Drupal 8 module

Tags: angular, drupal, angular6, drupal-modules, drupal-8

I need to wrap up my angular 6 app as Drupal 8 module. I tried to add `build files` (js, CSS, img) of angular application in Drupal module and defined it as libraries

In `drupal_angular.libraries.yml`

```
drupal_angular_lib:
  version: 1.x
  css:
    theme:
      css/bootstrap.min.css: {}
      css/demo.css: {}
      css/paper-dashboard.css: {}
      css/styles.a3a18ed7bbe6e603703b.css: {}
      css/themify-icons.css: {}
  js:
    js/main.5c5c8e529add0697c1bf.js: {}
    js/polyfills.a75b8d97ee951ee6b5c4.js: {}
    js/runtime.a66f828dca56eeb90e02.js: {}
    js/scripts.542a57744863c85b72b6.js: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
    - core/drupalSettings
```

Then, in my PHP code, I created a form and added this

```
$form['#attached']['library'][] = 'drupal_angular/drupal_angular_lib';
```

but, I am getting nothing here. I want to render my Angular application inside the Drupal(as a module).

Am I missing something? Is there a better way to implement this? Thanks.

Comment: Add console.log messages to the main module in Angular and make sure that the files are loading, and then make sure that the HTML tag that Angular is using to bootstrap exists.

Comment: `make sure that the HTML tag that Angular is using to bootstrap exists.` how do I check this? will I get that in `console.log()`?

Comment: In the main NgModule look at the component used to bootstrap the module. It's in the `bootstrap:` section. There has to be an HTML tag that matches the selector used by that component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first you should check that you load all the necessary scripts in the right order and that the paths are correct. For example, for the Angular 6 quick start project named `my-app`, and placed in the `app` directory in Drupal module, it should looks like this:

```
drupal_angular_lib:
  version: 1.x
  js:
    app/dist/my-app/runtime.js: {}
    app/dist/my-app/polyfills.js: {}
    app/dist/my-app/styles.js: {}
    app/dist/my-app/vendor.js: {}
    app/dist/my-app/main.js: {}
```

---

Also what is you probably missing is a HTML tag to which the Angular will attach the root application component.

I suggest to create custom block in a drupal module, something like that:

**drupal_angular/src/Plugin/Block/AngularAppBlock.php**

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\drupal_angular\Plugin\Block;

use Drupal\Core\Block\BlockBase;

/**
 * @Block(
 *   id = "drupal_angular",
 *   admin_label = @Translation("Drupal Angular"),
 *   category = @Translation("Custom"),
 * )
 */
class AngularAppBlock extends BlockBase
{

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function build()
  {
    return [
      '#type' => 'html_tag',
      '#tag' => 'app-root', // Selector of the your app root component from the Angular app
      '#attached' => [
        'library' => [
          'drupal_angular/drupal_angular_lib', // To load the library only with this block
        ],
      ],
    ];
  }

}
```

Then you can place this block with the Angular app anywhere you like through the Drupal admin interface.

---

Alternatively you can create a form:

**drupal_angular/src/Form/AngularAppForm.php**

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\drupal_angular\Form;

use Drupal\Core\Form\FormBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

class AngularAppForm extends FormBase
{

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getFormId()
    {
        return 'drupal_angular_app_form';
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state)
    {
        $form[] = [
          '#type' => 'html_tag',
          '#tag' => 'app-root',
          '#attached' => [
            'library' => [
              'drupal_angular/drupal_angular',
            ],
          ],
        ];
        return $form;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function validateForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state)
    {
        // TODO.
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state)
    {
        // TODO.
    }

}
```

And then, for example, just put this form in the routing:

**drupal_angular/drupal_angular.routing.yml**

```
drupal_angular.app_form:
  path: '/drupal-angular' # Path that you want for your form
  defaults:
    _title: 'Drupal Angular Form'
    _form: '\Drupal\drupal_angular\Form\AngularAppForm'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
```

---

Then check that you have actually enabled your module at `/admin/modules` page.

Also you may need to clear the site cache on the `/admin/config/development/performance`.

---

So it might look something like this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, It worked. I do have `assets` folders in my angular app which contains images, sass etc.  Can you please help me to add those files too. Much appreciated.

Comment: @NavaneethSelvaraj Drupal 8 serves public static files from the `sites/default/files` dir. I think it's easiest to put the Angular asset output there. You can copy it manually, set this up as an additional build step, or create a symlink from the files dir to the Angular output, or use path rewrite on the server... there are many ways to do it. Then you need to add the appropriate prefix to the asset URLs in your Angular application... I'm not sure how exactly this can be configured in the Angular 6. Probably you can just use absolute paths to assets, starting with `/sites/default/files/`.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I have a use case where I need to send and receive data from Angular to Drupal module and I believe that If I implement this module as a block, I can't do that. Can you please help me in creating a module as a form or in some other way so I can able to send and receive data using the proxy in PHP. Thanks.

Comment: @NavaneethSelvaraj, I have added the form example. But for any complex interaction with your Drupal site, you probably should create a service in your Angular app, that will use Drupal REST API. See https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/core/modules/rest

Comment: Or, instead of using the Drupal REST API, you can create a custom API controller in your module for needs of your Angular app.